# SQL Alchemy how to use OR_ with AND_

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm

Here is the code:

```
    if len(test1) > 0 or len(test2) > 0 or len(test3) > 0 or len(test4) > 0:
        filter_conditions = []

        if len(test1) > 0:
            filter_conditions.append(Object.test1.in_(test1))

        if len(test2) > 0:
            filter_conditions.append(Object.test2.in_(test2))

        if len(test3) > 0:
            filter_conditions.append(and_(Object.test3.in_(test3),
                                        Object.istest == 1))

        if len(test4) > 0:
            filter_conditions.append(and_(Object.test4.in_(test4),
                                        Object.istest == 1))

        final_filter_conditions = or_(*filter_conditions)
        count_query = count_query.filter(final_filter_conditions)
```

this return the result with where clause like this:

WHERE Object."istester" = :istester
AND (Object."test1" IN (**[test1_1]) OR Object."test2" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test2_1]) OR (Object."test3" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test3_2]) AND Object."istest" = :istest_1) OR Object."test4" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test4]) AND Object."istest" = :istest_2)

I want to achieve like this: need two brackets
WHERE Object."istester" = :istester
AND (Object."test1" IN (**[test1_1]) OR Object."test2" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test2_1]) OR (Object."test3" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test3_2]) AND Object."istest" = :istest_1) OR (Object."test4" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test4]) AND Object."istest" = :istest_2))'

Thanks

WHERE Object."istester" = :istester
AND (Object."test1" IN (**[test1_1]) OR Object."test2" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test2_1]) OR (Object."test3" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test3_2]) AND Object."istest" = :istest_1) OR Object."test4" IN (**[POSTCOMPILE_test4]) AND Object."istest" = :istest_2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .self_group() at the end of each clause.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseList.self_group